# how to insert into a table records from a table that have records in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have table `parent` and table `kids`, a parent can have some kids in the kids table (0 or more).

I want to insert to new table `parentWithKids` only the parents that have kids in the kids table.

So I tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO parentWithKids
SELECT *
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN kids k ON p.id = k.parent_id
```

but its not running...what is the issue here?

Comment: Please include the table definitions (columns names and types) for both the `parent` and `kids` tables.  We need to see this in order to help you.

Comment: Not related to your query problem, but instead of a table you should use a view here. That'll "refresh" it self where as the table needs to be updated when changes are done in `parent` or `kids`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume following schema.

**parent:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**kids**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kids` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**parentwithkids**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parentwithkids` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kids` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Here is the final query to retrieve the list of parents with number of kids.

```
INSERT INTO parentWithKids(parent_id, kids)
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, count(k.id)
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN kids k ON p.id = k.parent_id
GROUP BY k.parent_id
```